# why is javascript variable not changed across all the external JS files

Tags: javascript, jquery

Variable `a` is decared in the main file. Then `a.js` and `b.js` included. JS files have following content.

**a.js**:

```
a+=100;
```

**b.js**:

```
a=+200;
```

And the **main file**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     a=30;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/a.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/b.js"></script>
    a+=90;
    console.log("a = " + a);
</script>
```

Console shows `a=290`. Why is  `a`  not 420 (i.e. 30+100+200+90 ) ? why doesn't `a` change across both `a.js` and `b.js`?

Comment: did you make your a.js and b.js have different code for any specific reason? i.e. `a=+` vs `a+=`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You wrote the `+=` operator backwards. Written as `=+` the `+` is being interpreted as the unary `+` operator; in other words, you're explicitly assigning "positive 200" to the variable (in "b.js").

Comment: Thus, after setting a = 200 in b.js, you call a += 90 in the embedded script that follows the link to b.js resulting in a = 290 in your log

Comment: Actually it's not "positive 200", the + operator is a shortcut for "cast to Number". Try `+-200` in a console and you'll see `-200`. Same for `+"-200".`

Comment: @Plato well sure, but conceptually it's the opposite of `-`; the unary `+` operation is inherently idempotent, while unary `-` is not. That's why `+-200` is still negative.

Comment: @Plato, What a silly mistake I made ! Useful info these comments however !!

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo with `a =+ 200;` This assigns the global variable a the value 200.

I believe you meant `a += 200;`